# Java XML Reading

Tags: java, xml

I've been wondering how to read XML files, but before you answer, read the whole post.

For example I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<messages>

<incoming id="0" class="HelloIlikeyou" />

</messages>
```

What I want, is get all values from the tag . I want to place it in a dictionary, which key is incoming/outgoing, and then it will contain a list of Pair as value, with as key the id value and as value the class value.

So I got this:

```
HashMap<String, List<Pair<Integer, String>>> headers = new HashMap<>();
```

Then it will store this:

```
HashMap.get("incoming").add(new Pair<>("0", "HelloIlikeyou"));
```

But I don't know how to do it, I already got a part but it aint working:

```
File xml = new File(file);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xml);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("messages");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {

            Node node = nodes.item(i);

                System.out.println("Type: " + node.getNodeValue() + " packet ID " + node.getUserData("id"));    
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean "it aint working" (sic)? Getting exceptions? Not returning any data? Computer catches on fire?

Comment: You are still operating on the messages node, you have to iterate over node.getChildNodes()

Comment: could anyone answer this?
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24757825/how-to-read-xml-attribute-values-hierarchically-like-parentnodename-childnodeatt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
File xml = new File(file);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xml);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("messages");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nodes.item(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < node.getChildNodes().getLength(); j++) {

    Node child = node.getChildNodes().item(j);

    if (!child.getNodeName().equals("#text")) {
        NamedNodeMap attributes = child.getAttributes();

        System.out.println("Type: " + child.getNodeName()
            + " packet ID " + attributes.getNamedItem("id")
            + " - class: " + attributes.getNamedItem("class"));
    }
    }
}
}
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Type: incoming packet ID id="0" - class: class="HelloIlikeyou"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had to add:

    if (attributes == null) {
    continue;
    }

To prevent null errors (my project works on a way it will stop after a bug and because that was a null bug I got an error). Thanks anyway for this fix.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JAXB, i think that is the best way. take a look of this:
[Jaxb tutorial](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/)

Comment: JAXB, imo, provides the worst api among all xml serialization libs. XStream is far superior in api fluency and convenience. The reason behind it might be JAXB is a ref implementation and can't use exotic stuff like XStream.

Comment: Please provide a compelling reason for using this particular tool rather than just suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the many available libraries that will do that for you, for example XStream:

http://x-stream.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

```
Node node = nodes.item(i);
if (node instanceOf Element) {
    Element elem = (Element)node;
    String id = elem.getAttribute("id");
    ...
```

So you were almost there. The W3C classes are a bit old-stylish.