# How to read xml attribute values hierarchically like parentNodeName.ChildNodeAttributeName?

Tags: java, xml

### this is my xml file test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Class name="AirwayBill">
    <Attribute name="billNo" primary="true" />
    <Attribute name="date" primary="true" />
    <Attribute name="person" class_name="Person" />
</Class>
<Class name="Person">
    <Attribute name="perId" primary="true" />
    <Attribute name="fname" primary="false" />
    <Attribute name="lname" primary="false" />
</Class>
```

i want to read this xml file in such a way i should get attribute
 values like Classname.attributeName----->e.g AirwayBill.billNo, Person.fname, Person.perId etc.
how do i achieve that?
plz explain in detail as m new to using xml

Comment: Consider using xpath. http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/07/how-to-work-with-xpaths-in-java-with-examples/

Comment: Try [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)

Comment: could u plz explain me in detail. i am able to read the names individually like persid, billNo, date, person etc, bt i want to read it in this format AirwayBill.billNo

Comment: BTW the above is not a well-formed XML document ... it has more than one top-level element. An attempt to parse it will fail. You can fix that by wrapping the top-level `<Class>` elements in a parent element, e.g. `<Classes>`.

Comment: yeah i have a root element called <Root>.. it was nt fitting in the format so removed it